# Python: can't instantiate my object from inside another object: 'global name not defined'

Tags: python, nameerror

Hi all and thanks in advance for any help.

I am learning Python and working on a Zork style adventure game to practise.

Once I've defined classes my first actual instruction is

```
ourGame = Game('githyargi.txt')
```

where githyargi.txt is a file containing all the game's strings. method Game.parseText() works as documented.

Traceback shows the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "githyargi.py", line 237, in <module>
    ourGame = Game('githyargi.txt')
  File "githyargi.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.scenes[0] = Start()
  File "githyargi.py", line 166, in __init__
    for string in ourGame.strings['FIRST']:
NameError: global name 'ourGame' is not defined
```

If I do `ourGame.scenes[0] = Start()` from the execution block it works great- no name error, and `self.scenes[0].flavStr` gets filled up with the appropriate flavour text. However I want to create a method `Game.makeScenes()` that will create all the scenes in the game and store them in list `ourGame.scenes`. Why can't the **init** of Start() see ourGame.strings when instantiated from the **init** of Game(), when it can see the same dict when instantiated from the execution block?

```
class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        '''creates a new map, calls parseText, initialises the game status dict.'''
        self.strings = self.parseText(filename)
        self.sceneIndex = 0
        self.scenes = []
        self.scenes[0] = Start()
        self.status = {
            "Health": 100,
            "Power": 10,
            "Weapon": "Unarmed",
            "Gizmo": "None",
            "Turn": 0,
            "Alert": 0,
            "Destruct": -1
            }

    def parseText(self, filename):
        '''Parses the text file and extracts strings into a dict of
        category:[list of strings.]'''
        textFile = open(filename)
        #turn the file into a flat list of strings and reverse it
        stringList = []; catList = [] ; textParsed = {}
        for string in textFile.readlines():
            stringList.append(string.strip())
        stringList.reverse()

        #make catList by popping strings off stringList until we hit '---'
        for i in range(0, len(stringList)):
            string = stringList.pop()

            if string == '---':
                break
            else:
                catList.append(string)

        #Fill categories
        for category in catList:
            newList = []
            for i in range(0, len(stringList)):
                string = stringList.pop()

                if string == '---':
                    break
                else:
                    newList.append(string)

            textParsed[category] = newList

        return textParsed

class Scene(object):

    def __init__(self):
        '''sets up variables with null values'''
        self.sceneType = 'NULL'
        self.flavStr = "null"
        self.optStr = "null"
        self.scenePaths = []

class Start(Scene):

    def __init__(self):
        self.flavStr = ""
        for string in ourGame.strings['FIRST']:
            self.flavStr += '\n'
            self.flavStr += string
        self.optStr = "\nBefore you lies a dimly lit corridor. (1) to boldly go."
        self.scenePaths = [1]
```

Comment: that will be `self.strings['FIRST']` instead.

Comment: First all the code in the `Game()` constructor is executed, then the result is assigned to `ourGame`. But you're trying to use `ourGame` inside of the constructor. Just looking at the code you posted, yeah, there's no `ourGame` defined anywhere within scope of `Start`.

Comment: thanks all for the help. =)

Comment: Good grief. Hey, if you too are learning to code and want to see evidence of your progress, just look back at code you wrote 18 months ago or so! What a mess lol. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a timing thing. When you do

```
ourGame = Game('githyargi.txt')
```

Then first the Game instance is created, and only then is it assigned to ourGame.

Instead, pass the Game to use to the constructor of Scene, and pass `self` so it becomes something like

```
self.scenes.append(Start(self))
```

Note that you also can't do `scenes = []` and then set `scenes[0]` on the next line -- an empty list doesn't have an element 0.

Comment: Not really timing as much as dependency logic…

Comment: Two bugs squished for the price of one- thanks Remco.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I created a new method- Game.makeScenes(x) that appends x number of scenes to ourGame.scenes. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: @V.G You should really be passing dependencies around explicitly instead of relying on implicitly defined global variables…

Comment: @deceze I'm now doing this in my child class-  e.g. `super(Corridor, self).__init__()` to pass inherited attributes down. I'm not sure if that's what you mean- I'm still in the part of the learning curve where I'm not 100% on what to call everything and therefore asking for help is still an inexact science, lol.